# statistical careers where you get to move around?

Tags: careers

I'm about to get my PhD. My background is in engineering and applied mathematics. My research in statistical & machine learning methods for biological applications (without being too specific).

I love mathematics and doing research, but I'm astoundingly terrible at politics and I think I have 0 chance of success in academia. I've looked into (and done internships in) corporate engineering & data-science positions, and it's not for me. I've also taught and, oh boy, I am not a teacher.

I'd really love work where I got to move around a lot (not staring at a computer all day), and where I got to work closely with a small team. I don't mean a career where I had to travel a lot to different cities necessarily, but rather one where I just physically have to go places and talk to people and maybe work with physical objects on occasion.

Do you have any suggestions for career paths where I might combine these desires with my love of mathematics?

Comment: I voted to close this as I fear answers will be primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

What about consultancy in data science etc?

Comment: even management consultants who need some statistical support